# Android: Searching a String ArrayList with string

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

So I have a string arraylist with values

```
    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and the users input as a String

```
    EditText iSearchValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iQuestion);
    String sSearchValue = iSearchValue.getText().toString();
```

Now my question is, how do I loop through the length of the ArrayList to check if any value in the array contains what the user inputted in the sSearchValue String.

I looked in the documentations and guides but I am still kind of confused, having a solid example related to what Im doing would help my understanding a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
for(String s : urls)
{
    if(sSearchValue.contains(s) == true)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a question, what is String s? Is it just an example and Im supposed to replace it with something? If so, what am I supposed to replace it with?

Comment: That is not a normal for loop. It is a for each loop so `String s` is a `String` which is changing each time the loop restarts. The loop goes throught every item from your `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You could even use a guava library and use predicates to search through the list without looping.

Like

```
class SearchForString implements 
Predicate<String>{

// create constructor here and pass search string
// initialize the searchstring local variable with     the parameter passed in the constuctor


 // override the method here
// inside the method
// return value

    return stringVar.equals(searchString);
}
```

Call the predicate like this:

```
String value = Iterables.find(arraylistofstring, new SearchForString(searchstring), null);
```